# foreach within \draw, without giving the first point explicitly

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I am plotting line given by y(x) expression evaluated at regularly spaced points, e.g.

```
\def\ffIiC{+0.0436275-1.18778*\x^1+0.542693*\x^2}
% ...
\draw (0,0.0436275) \foreach\x in {0,.1,...,4}{ -- ({\x},{\ffIiiC}) };
%     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

However, I always need to specify the first point explicitly. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Having always a small MWE allows other people to simply copy and paste it and test their solutions. TikZ is complex enough that solutions should be tested previous before posting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `--` without a previous coordinate seems to be the issue.
You can add a conditional to have the `--` suppressed for the first value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikz {
    \def\ffIiC{+0.0436275-1.18778*\x^1+0.542693*\x^2}
    \draw \foreach\x in {0,.1,...,4} {
            \ifdim\x pt=0pt \else--\fi
            ({\x},{\ffIiC})
    };
}
\end{document}
```

Note: The space before `\else` is important, otherwise an error is caused. TeX seems to add an implicit `\relax` as terminator for the dimension expression in that case which breaks the TikZ path.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote it shorter with `count` as `\draw \foreach\x [count=\xi] in {0,.1,...,4}{ \ifnum\xi=1 \else--\fi ({\x},{\ffIiC}) };` but it still feels more awkward than I would like it to be...

Comment: Yes, it doesn't look that nice. It would be nice if you could give special code for the first and maybe last iteration.

Comment: It's preferable to avoid the conditional inside the `\foreach` (time consuming). I prefer to keep the first point outside and in this case, the loop begins with `0.1` and not `0`.

Comment: @Altermundus: Yes, but this means code repetition. In this case it is still manageable, but in general a nicer solution would be great.

Comment: Isn't there way to give some not-a-point (like NaN) coordinate to TikZ, so that the first point would be simply ignored?